# подскажите новичку org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

делаю проект: в xml конфигурации все работает, при переходе на аннотацию выдает эту ошибку.

Работающий applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="bestuser" />
        <property name="password" value="bestuser" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


</beans>
```

мои конфиги:
applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


</beans>
```

без изменений web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-mvc-hibernate-aop</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

MyConfig:

```
package com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop")
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false");
            dataSource.setUser("bestuser");
            dataSource.setPassword("bestuser");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.spring.rest.entity");

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                "true");

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум не хватает `com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop` в `@ComponentScan`, в xml от присутствует.

Comment: добавление aop не помогло

Comment: Обновите вопрос, чтоб код, который вы используете после этого, нужного, исправления был актуальный. Может вы опечатку допустили, а мы то этого не видим.

Comment: Обновил код, убрал aop из xml конфигурации, работает корректно, в версии с config та же ошибка

Comment: Вы что-то не то сделали. Прочитайте еще раз первый комментарий, я про `component-scan`. У вас в xml сканируются классы в `com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop`, а в java конфиге - не сканируются. Неудивительно, что классы из того пакета не находятся.

Comment: Компоненты мы просканировали, а Entity сканируются несколько иначе.
EntityScan vs. ComponentScan
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-entityscan-vs-componentscan

Comment: спасибо это оно и было @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.spring.mvc_hibernate_aop")